# Limit of a covariance sequence

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

I've been struggling on the following exercice lately :

> Consider $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ a sequence of mutually independent real-valued random variables, standardized, that follow any given law.
> Let $Y$ be a real random variable such that $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is finite. What is the limit of $(\mathbb{E}[Y X_n])_{n\ge 1}$ ?

Let's write the variance-covariance matrix of the vector $(Y,X_1,\dots,X_n)$. We will denote this $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix by $\Sigma_n$:
$$\Sigma_n = \begin{pmatrix} \operatorname{Var}[Y] & \operatorname{Cov}(Y, X_{1}) &  \cdots & \operatorname{Cov}(Y,X_{n}) \\
\operatorname{Cov}(Y, X_{1}) & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\operatorname{Cov}(Y, X_{n}) & \cdots & \cdots&  \operatorname{Var}[X_n]
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \operatorname{Var}[Y] & \mathbb{E}[YX_1] & \cdots & \cdots & \mathbb{E}[YX_n] \\
\mathbb{E}[YX_1] & 1 & 0 & \cdots  & 0\\
\vdots & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\mathbb{E}[YX_{n-1}] & \vdots & \ddots & 1 &  0\\
\mathbb{E}[YX_n] & 0 & \cdots & 0 &  1
\end{pmatrix}$$

We used the fact that the $X_i$ are normalized and mutually independent.

One thing that we know with this type of matrix is that, to be a covariance matrix, it has to be **positive semi-definite**. In particular, its eigenvalues are positive. Thus we can have a look at the roots of the $\lambda$-polynomial $\text{det}(\Sigma_n - \lambda I_{n+1}).$ I do end up with a recursive expression for this determinant by developing the last line, but it doesn't seem to be enough to conclude. We also have $\displaystyle \sum \operatorname{eigenvalues} = \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma_n) = \operatorname{Var}[Y] + n.$

Do you have any other ideas to solve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Taking a step back, can you give an example where $X_n$ has all the properties listed and $\mathrm{Cov} (Y, X_n) \neq 0$, and $E Y X_n$ depends on $n$?

Comment: @Galton I tried to think about something but found no trivial sequence. That is why my guess would be that it converges towards 0 and my goal was to find a sufficient condition that implies that rather than an explicit formulae.

Comment: It is weird that $Y$ and $X_n$ can be dependent but the $X_n$ are independent and $Y$ cannot depend on $n$. This makes me think that this may not be a well-posed question.

Comment: Cannot say, I picked it up from an exam as it seemed interesting but I have nowhere to ask for a solution. No idea from a context where this problem would naturally arise either.